# How to pass a member callback function by reference

Tags: c++, http, oop, c++11, asynchronous

I am trying to implement a method to deal with the HTTP requests in C++, but I ran into some trivial problems. I tried to encapsulate the functions into two different classes, and when I don't know how should I pass a callback function by reference when the callback function is implemented as a non-static member function, any suggestions?

Thank you!

Following are some of my implementations:

```js
// my_lib.hpp
#include <functional>

class my_lib {
public:
    // A library to handle the HTTP requests
    using request_callback = std::function<void(int response_code, const std::string &data)>;
    void perform_request(std::string &url, std::string &body, const request_callback &callback);
};


// my_lib.cpp
#include "my_lib.hpp"
#include <string>

void my_lib::perform_request(std::string &url, std::string &body, const request_callback &callback) {
    
    // Do http request...
    std::string str("...");
    callback(200, str);
}


// myClass.hpp
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include "my_lib.hpp"

class myClass {
public:
    using request_callback = std::function<void(int response_code, const std::string &data)>;
    void on_action_callback(int response_code, const std::string &data);
    void on_action_endpoint(const std::string &request, const request_callback &callback);
private:
    my_lib* lib_instance;
};


// myClass.cpp
#include "myClass.hpp"

void myClass::on_action_callback(int response_code, const std::string &data) {
    // do something
}

void myClass::on_action_endpoint(const std::string &request, const request_callback &callback) {
    int code = 0;
    
    // TODO: how should I pass the on_action_callback here....
    lib_instance->perform_request("a.com", "a", myClass::on_action_callback);
}
```

Comment: There's always `std::function`.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap into a lambda:

```
lib_instance->perform_request("a.com", "a", 
    [this](int response_code, const std::string &data) 
    { on_action_callback(response_code, data); });
```

here `this` should be captured to be able to call member function. Another option is to `bind` `this` with a `std::function` constructed from your member function, but you don't really need this complexity here